# What is provided to `self.included` (typically named `base`) in ruby?

Tags: ruby, metaprogramming, ruby-module

I'm trying to understand ruby metaprogramming a bit better and while I have workarounds for what I want to do, I would like to make it as clean as possible.

Simply put I would like to check if the class that includes a module has defined a given method:

```
irb(main):058:1* module A
irb(main):059:2*   def self.included(base)
irb(main):060:2*     puts base.singleton_method(:singleton_test)
irb(main):061:1*   end
irb(main):062:0> end
:included
irb(main):063:1* class B
irb(main):064:1*   include A
irb(main):065:2*   def self.singleton_test
irb(main):066:2*     puts "hi"
irb(main):067:1*   end
irb(main):068:0> end
```

I would expect this to output something like the following:

`#<Method: B.singleton_test() (irb):95>`

However, it does not:

```
(irb):60:in `singleton_method': undefined singleton method `singleton_test' for `B' (NameError)

    puts base.singleton_method(:singleton_test)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

I suspect it's because the singleton methods are not bound to `base` yet when the `included` hook is called.

How would I go about checking for `singleton_test` being defined in this pattern?

PS Maybe also worth noting this seems to happen with any method definitions on `base` at the time `Module A` is included, singleton or instance.

Comment: Given the dynamic nature of Ruby, testing for the existence of a method at some point (e.g. upon module inclusion) is somewhat unreliable. You should defer that check until you actually have to call the method. Or maybe have no check in the first place and let it raise an exception.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback @Stefan. This seems like the correct methodology, appreciate the advice.

Comment: @Stefan if you have anymore good advice to share I asked a related question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77460372/how-do-module-level-method-overrides-work-in-ruby

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a simple ordering issue.

Ruby is (mostly) evaluated left-to-right top-to-bottom.

```ruby
class B
  include A

  def self.singleton_test
    puts('hi')
  end
end
```

As you can see, the `include` comes before the method definition. You need to swap the two around:

```ruby
class B
  def self.singleton_test
    puts('hi')
  end

  include A
  # #<Method: B.singleton_test() ./test.rb:2>
end
```

Comment: Ah, so the methods were in fact unbound at the time of inclusion. Thanks! This answers my question, as far as methodology goes I'll take Stefan's advice.

Comment: @ohhh methods are not unbound at time of inclusion, they simply do not exist. AS mentioned the lexical parser is left to right, top to bottom. So at the point of inclusion in the first example (same as your example) the parser has not seen the definition for `B::singleton_test` and thus it does not exist (or is "undefined").

Comment: Yes, I see the distinction, thanks, I understand `UnboundMethod` is different than nothing