# How do module level method overrides work in ruby?

Tags: ruby, metaprogramming, ruby-module

I have some code based on this SO answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2136117/2158544. Essentially it looks like this (note: **in the actual code, I do not control module A)**:

```
module A
  def self.included(base)
    base.extend ClassMethods
  end
  module ClassMethods
    def singleton_test
    end
  end
end

module B
  def self.included(base)
    base.extend ClassMethods
  end

  module ClassMethods
    def self.extended(base)
      puts base.method(:singleton_test).owner
      define_method(:singleton_test) do |*args, &blk|
        super(*args, &blk)
      end
    end
  end
end
```

First inclusion:

```
class C
  include A
  include B
end
A::ClassMethods # <- output
```

Second inclusion:

```
class D
  include A
  include B
end
B::ClassMethods # <- output
```

Although the call to `super` still gets correctly routed to `module A`, I'm confused why `singleton_test` is already "wrapped" when it gets included into `class D` (owner is `B::ClassMethods`). My theory is that it's because when `module B` redefines `singleton_test`, it's redefining it on the included module level (`module A`) and thus every time `module A` gets included subsequently, the method has already been "wrapped".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you call a method ruby walks up the ancestral chain looking for the method, if it reaches the top (BasicObject) and cannot find a matching method it will throw an error (unless `method_missing` is defined)

How this works in your example

**First Inclusion**

```
C.singleton_class.ancestors
#=> [#<Class:C>, B::ClassMethods, A::ClassMethods, #<Class:Object>, #<Class:BasicObject>, Class, Module, Object, Kernel, BasicObject]
```

When you lookup `singleton_test` it checks the ancestral chain

- C - No method
- B::ClassMethods - No method
- A::ClassMethods - Found `singleton_test`

Now in the `B::ClassMethods::extended` hook you are defining `singleton_test` using `define_method`. Since you called this method without a receiver the implicit receiver is `self` and `self` in the context of this method is `B::ClassMethods` so in essence you are calling

```
module B 
  module ClassMethods 
    def singleton_test(*args,&blk) 
      super(*args, &blk)
    end 
  end 
end
```

You can see this more clearly as

```
puts "Before B inclusion: #{B::ClassMethods.instance_methods(false)}"
class C
  include A
  include B 
end
puts "After B inclusion: #{B::ClassMethods.instance_methods(false)}"
```

Output:

```
Before B inclusion: []
After B inclusion: [:singleton_test]
```

**Second Inclusion**

I think you can see where this is going

```
D.singleton_class.ancestors
#=> [#<Class:D>, B::ClassMethods, A::ClassMethods, #<Class:Object>, #<Class:BasicObject>, Class, Module, Object, Kernel, BasicObject]
```

When you lookup `singleton_test` it checks the ancestral chain

- D - No method
- B::ClassMethods - Found `singleton_test`

So it is not that the method is "already wrapped" or that the method is being redefined on `A` it is that you have defined a new method in `B::ClassMethods` and since `B` is included after `A` it's definition takes priority (overrides that of `A` in this context).

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but I think you may be slightly misunderstanding my question. I understand that at the time `module A` is included into `class C` the owner of `singleton_test` is A, then when `module B` is included it re-defines `singleton_test` and becomes the owner on `class C`. What I don't understand is why *class D* still thinks that that `module B` is the owner of `singleton_test` at the time of inclusion of `module B`. I would expect `class D` (which is the same logically as `class C` to have the exact same output after being created.

Comment: @ohhh `include` / `extend` don't copy the methods into the class, they just add the modules to the list of ancestors for method lookup, i.e. the methods stay in the modules they were defined in (hence the distinction between _owner_ and _receiver_). Calling `define_method` doesn't _re_-define an existing `singleton_test`, it defines a _new_ `singleton_test` inside `B::ClassMethods`. And because `B` was included after `A` it takes precedence from there on.

Comment: @ohhh if you move `puts base.method(:singleton_test).owner` _after_ the `define_method` call, you'll see that both output `B::ClassMethods`. It's a matter of execution order because you define a method dynamically.

Comment: I see. One follow up though: I don't see anything very harmful in doing things this way in terms of functionality. After the first inclusion of `module B`, the subsequent inclusions on any class will just redefine the existing `singleton_test` method on `module B` to be the same as it was on the last inclusion if I understand correctly. Calling `super` will result in a call to `module A` (higher up the chain) and I think life will be good. Is there anything you would recommend doing differently in order to "wrap" a method like this though?

Comment: @ohhh I am a bit unclear on the actual desire in this case as the question itself seemed more educational than functional. If you have a functional need along these lines the continued redefinition seems unnecessary as you could just define the method through standard syntax (e.g. `def singleton_test`) which would reduce some overhead and make the intention clearer. The other concern I can see is the reliance  on the existence of a method (e.g. the `super` call) in a module you don't control but this would be a design decision you'd have to make for your use case.

Comment: I want to override the `perform_*` methods on sidekiq so that I can define rules within the job instances that will be enforced within a module before a job is enqueued. For instance if some condition is met at the time `perform_async` is called it will check a method on the job called `enqueuing_rules` and reject it if the conditions within `enqueuing_rules` are not met. Not too worried about `super` since the sidekiq interface is stable. I agree about the standard syntax, maybe I'll define manually instead of looping through a regex match on public methods matching /perform_.*/.

Comment: @ohhh it now sound like a [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) – instead of asking about your actual problem (_"I want to override the `perform_*` methods on sidekiq"_), you asked about your attempted solution, i.e. method lookup and meta programming :-) You might want to post a new question regarding your Sidekiq problem in particular.

Comment: @ohhh one additional comment would be that you are relying on the inclusion of `A` in a very specific order with `B`. Since `B` inherently relies on the inclusion of `A` I would recommend moving that inclusion into the `B::included` hook (e.g. `base.include(A) unless base.include?(A)`). This removes the need to include `A` explicitly and better characterizes the tight coupling you are creating between `B` and `A`.